# jquery on click, on page load add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

## Solved

1st this was created for another problem, but i solve it because of some sloppy moves by me...anyway i got another problem and that is adding class `current` on `li`, with `data-tab="tab-1`, on page load.

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
```

```css
.tabs li.current {
  color: red;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
 }
.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="innovation">
  <div class="categories-wrap">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Pristine coverage</h4>
        <p>Enjoy your calls without interuptions like dropped calls, poor sound quality, and delayed video.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Chat messaging</h4>
        <p>Chat in real time with connections all around the world. </p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Video calling</h4>
        <p>WiFi paired with reliable cellular service is how we’ve got you covered in more places than ever before.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Photo share</h4>
        <p>WiFi paired with reliable cellular service is how we’ve got you covered in more places than ever before.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-wrap">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      <img src="" alt="Pristine Coverage">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Chat Messaging">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Video Calling">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Photo Share">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".current").removeClass("current");
  $(".tabs-wrap #tab-1").addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: nope :-/ basicly other tabs are hidden but when i click on 2nd tab it won't add class on him

Comment: @Soullighter Check your fiddle, doesn't look like it is working.

Comment: ok, i must say, this is weird. anyway, thank you for your time tho

Answer (score 0):

Simply trigger a click on the first tab on page load:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
});

//Trigger click on first tab
$("[data-tab='tab-1']").click();
```

```css
.tabs li.current {
  color: red;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="innovation">
  <div class="categories-wrap">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Pristine coverage</h4>
        <p>Enjoy your calls without interuptions like dropped calls, poor sound quality, and delayed video.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Chat messaging</h4>
        <p>Chat in real time with connections all around the world.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Video calling</h4>
        <p>WiFi paired with reliable cellular service is how we’ve got you covered in more places than ever before.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">
        <i class="sprite-call-black"></i>
        <h4>Photo share</h4>
        <p>WiFi paired with reliable cellular service is how we’ve got you covered in more places than ever before.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-wrap">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      <img src="" alt="Pristine Coverage">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Chat Messaging">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Video Calling">
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      <img src="" alt="Photo Share">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```